# Create a left pointed UIBarButton in a UINavigation Bar Programmatically

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, navigation, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I'm trying to create an app with a settings page just like IOS's native settings app. However I cannot find out how to create a UIBarButton that is left pointed. Basically I want a left pointed button on the top of a navigation bar, that you can set to call a function. I am using the engine cocos2d, if this helps. I am creating the entire app programmatically.

Here is my code for creating the UINavigationBar...

```
UINavigationBar *naviBarObj = [[[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 44)] autorelease];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:naviBarObj];
[naviBarObj release];
UINavigationItem *item = [[[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"] autorelease];
UIBarButtonItem *back = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                        target:self
                                                        action:@selector(back)] autorelease];
item.leftBarButtonItem = back;
[naviBarObj setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:item, nil] animated:YES];
```

Although this creates a square back button.

My goal is to create something like this

[image: Left Pointed Button]

I am aware that a UINavigationItem

`UINavigationItem *back2 = [[[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Settings"] autorelease];`

with `[naviBarObj setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:back,item, nil] animated:YES];`

will create that effect, but unfortunately I am not currently using a UINavigationController class. This is all made in a CCLayer.

Thank You!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use a custom back image, but that would be kind of tedious.

Another way would be like exactly what you mentioned in your last part, to create another "dummy" previous navigation item with the title set to the text you want to be on your back button, and then adding both items to the UINavigationBar.

```
UINavigationItem *item = [[[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"] autorelease];    
UINavigationItem *back2 = [[[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Settings"] autorelease];

[naviBarObj setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:back2,item, nil] animated:YES];
```

However I don't think you will need a UINavigationController for these to happen. In order to handle your back button event, I suppose you can try making your CCLayer a delegate of UINavigationBar, ie. UINavigationBarDelegate:

```
@interface MyLayer : CCLayer <UINavigationBarDelegate> {
}
```

then setting the delegate of your UINavigationBar to that layer:

```
naviBarObj.delegate = self;
```

and finally implement didPopItem to get notified of the event when the button is clicked:

```
- (void) navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar didPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item
{
    [self back]; // or whatever 
}
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: This worked. Although when I touch the item, the UINavigationBar is animated and the scene below has no animation whatsoever. If I try to use a `CCTransitionSlideInR` it just jumps to the target scene, no animation at all. Is there a way I can achieve this without using a UINavigationController class. Thanks!

Comment: The two main views are UITableViews, if this helps

Comment: so do you want the "back" transition to be animated or no? And what are these "two main views"? Are they for "Settings" and "Title" respectively?

Comment: Go on an iphones settings app, click any cell, that is the transition i want to create. yes i want the back transition to be animated. Yes the two views are "Settings" and "General"